# Infinite loop in program

Tags: c, process, infinite-loop, exit

One of the components in my process calling assignment seems to be running an infinite loop and I can't tell why. here seems to be the problem area

```
D=fork();
if (D==0)execv("/home/8/myfiles/DD.c",arg);


while(temp != 4){               //return value of D is 4
A = wait(&temp);}
exit(1);
```

The goal of the code is to wait until D terminates. Like the comment says, D ends with "exit(4);" so as far as I'm aware, that means that when it does temp will be assigned 4, right? Or am I doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The value returned into `temp` by `wait()` does not return the exit status of the exited application; it returns a packed value which *includes* the exit code, if applicable.

Use the macros defined in [the manual page for `wait()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait), such as `WIFEXITED()` and `WEXITSTATUS()`, to determine what the status code means. Keep in mind that, if your subprocess terminates abnormally (e.g, crashes), `wait()` may return a value other than the one you're hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
if (D==0)execv("/home/8/myfiles/DD.c",arg);
```

seems like it should be:

```
if (D==0)execv("/home/8/myfiles/DD",arg);
```

Regardless, a more robust way of dealing with waiting for the child process is:

```
A = wait(&temp);
if(temp != 4)
{
    // Print a message or do whatever makes sense
    // to deal with the unexpected value.
}

exit(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is rather sloppily written.  You should be testing the return values from system calls that can fail (or, in the case of `execv()`, simply reporting that it returned and then exiting).  Your loop code should take into account that if the SIGCHLD signal is ignored, you may never get a valid status from `wait()`.  And, as pointed out by [duskwuff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149341/duskwuff) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28336652/15168), you should be using the proper macros to test the exit status.  Your current test will, empirically, test whether the child terminated because it received signal 4 (SIGILL on Mac OS X).

I think you should be using code more like:

```
int pid;
if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
    exit(1);
}
if (pid == 0)
{
    const char *cmd = "/home/8/myfiles/DD.c";
    execv(cmd, arg);
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to execute %s\n", cmd);
    exit(1);
}

int corpse;
int status;
while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
{
    if (WIFEXITED(status) && WEXITSTATUS(status) == 4)
        break;
    printf("PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
}
exit(0);
```

You could check that the corpse is the same as the PID — that is more reliable than just checking the exit status.  You might decide you don't want the printing in the wait loop; that's legitimate, though you might keep it for debugging purpose.  You might also print the PID of the child before you enter the loop.  Note that it is necessary to loop even if you know that the only process your program has started is the one in the `fork()`.  When a process execs another, if the first process has children, the execed process still has those as its own children, and they might terminate before the forked and execed process.

It is unusual to have an executable (program or script) called `DD.c`; a name ending `.c` is normally a C source file.  It is usually best to use:

```
execv(args[0], args);
```

so that the name of the executable is the name of the command.  It is not mandatory, though.  It is usually a good idea to report the name of the command that could not be executed if the command execution fails.